# python PIL png text get messed up

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, png

I would like to merge multiple png that I generated with matplotlib into a new png.
Now, when I load and save any png with PIL the text gets totally screwed up and becomes unreadable.

```
from PIL import Image

img_zraw_box = Image.open('tmp_zraw_box0.png')
img_result = Image.new('RGB', (img_zraw_box.width, img_zraw_box.height))
img_result.paste(img_zraw_box, (0, 0))
img_result.save('tmp_zraw_box1.png')
```

original matplotlib png:
[image]

png open, past and saved with PIL:
[image]

Has anyone and idea what goes wrong, and how I could fix this?
Thank you, Elmar

Comment: You have missed some important detail. I am fairly certain that pasting an image in **PIL** did not add all that text, annotation, axes and titles.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the only thing I do, I take the first png, run the code above and get the second png. Please try and if you get another output load it up here. 
I tried on two different computers (both linux)  and I get the same result. 
Please have a close look. Text and title are all in the first image. They just get fat and ugly passing them PIL.

Comment: On, I see. The top image is annotated, just almost invisibly! Try adding  an extra parameter to the `paste()` like this `img_result.paste(img_zraw_box, (0, 0), img_zraw_box)`

Comment: Excellent- glad it worked. It's late here. You are welcome to write it up as an answer and accept it and grab the points. Or I'll try to find a moment to do it tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, you are a wizard! 
I just read the doc string. This is the mask parameter that we set. Good to know. Actually, by Image.new I have to set the color to 'white' that it really worked. But that totally solves the problem. The point is yours! I will write the correct code for you in a comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: ```
from PIL import Image

img_zraw_box = Image.open('tmp_zraw_box0.png')
img_result = Image.new('RGB', (img_zraw_box.width, img_zraw_box.height), color='white')
img_result.paste(img_zraw_box, (0, 0), mask=img_zraw_box)
img_result.save('tmp_zraw_box1.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the `mask` parameter to your **PIL** `paste()` call so that the alpha channel is properly respected:

```
from PIL import Image
img_zraw_box = Image.open('tmp_zraw_box0.png')

# Create a solid white background to paste onto
img_result = Image.new('RGB', (img_zraw_box.width, img_zraw_box.height), color='white')

# Paste with alpha mask
img_result.paste(img_zraw_box, (0, 0), mask=img_zraw_box)
img_result.save('tmp_zraw_box1.png')
```